# Laravel: whereHas() with complex conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have two models let's say,

**Block** and **Slot** with their respective table structure as:-

```
blocks(id, name);
slots(id, block_id, time, status);
```

`slots.status` may have values as `0` for available or `1` for booked.

The problem is, I want to return those blocks only whose `status` count `1` vs the total slots count ratio in the slots table is less than 0.5 or in another term, I want to return those blocks whose slots are available more than 50% for booking.

I have a laravel eloquent logic as follows:-

```
$blocks = Block::whereHas('slots', function ($q) {
    // What might be the condition here... ?
})
->with('slots');
```

Comment: Have you made plain sql query of that request already?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood the formula but if you want to get blocks where there are more available slots, you could do this:

```
$blocks = Block::withCount(['slots as booked' => function($q) {
    $q->where('status', 1);
}])
->withCount(['slots as available' => function($q) {
    $q->where('status', 0);
}])
->get();

$blocks = $blocks->filter(function ($block) {
    return $block->booked > $block->available;
});
```